# Routing Error No route matches [POST]"/contacts/new

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I seem to be stuck on a Ruby on Rails tutorial. I keep getting the error that is in the title of this post, which is:

Routing Error No route matches[POST]"/contacts/new"

app/views/contacts/new.html.erb

```
<div class="container">
<div class="rpw">
    <h3 class="text-center">Contact Us</h3>

    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
        <%= flash[:notice] %>
        <div class="well">
            <%= form_for "/contacts" do |f| %>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <%= f.label :name %>
                    <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <%= f.label :email %>
                    <%= f.text_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <%= f.label :comments %>
                    <%= f.text_area :comments, class: 'form-control' %>
                    </div>
                <%= f.submit 'Submit', class: 'btn btn-success' %>
        <% end %>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
root to: 'pages#home'
get 'about', to: 'pages#about'
resources :contacts
```

end

contacts_controller.rb

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController
def new
    @contact = Contact.new
end

def create
    @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)
    if @contact.save
        redirect_to new_contact_path, notice: "Message sent."
    else
        redirect_to new_contact_path, notice: "Error occured"
    end
end

    private
    def contact_params
        params.require(:contact).permit(:name, :email, :comments)
    end
```

end

contact.rb

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
```

end

I am unsure where I am going wrong. Please help me. I have been trying to fix this for a few days now.

Comment: try <%= form_for @contact do |f| %>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In new.html.erb

try changing

```
    <%= form_for "/contacts" do |f| %>
```

to

```
     <%= form_for @contact do |f| %>
```

Comment: No problem. Not sure where you got `/contacts` from, but you have defined `@contact` in you `new` method in your controller. This means that in new.html.erb this variable is available.